# Convert string to number

Tags: javascript

I have some simple variables whose values are numeric strings:

```
var s = '10*10*10',
    v = '60*10';
```

I want to turn `s` into `1000` and `v` to `600`.

Comment: only for the multiplication operator?

Comment: Where did these values come from?

Comment: @tomalak it comes from yaml, which is a config file.

Comment: If you trust the contents of the config file not to contain malicious script code where you're expecting these values, `eval` is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `eval()` function:

```
var result = eval('10*10*10');
alert(result); // alerts 1000
```

Comment: Yes but I can't upvote this answer as you do not qualify it with any warnings about when this would be an incredibly bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

***If*** the strings are from a truly trusted source, you can use `eval` to do that:

```
var s = '10*10*10';
var result = eval(s);
```

**But** note that `eval` fires up a JavaScript parser, parses the given string, and executes it. If there's any chance that the given string may not be from a trusted source, you don't want to use it, as you're giving the source the ability to arbitrarily execute code.

If you can't trust the source, then you'll have to parse the string yourself. Your specific examples are easy, but I'm sure your actual need is more complex.

The dead easy bit:

```
var s, operands, result, index;
s = '10*10*10';
operands = s.split('*');
result = parseInt(operands[0], 10); 
for (index = 1; index < operands.length; ++index) {
    result *= parseInt(operands[index], 10);
}
```

...but again, I'm sure your actual requirement is more complex — other operators, spaces around the values, parentheses, etc.

---

Picking up on Andy E's comment below, whitelisting might well be a way to go:

```
function doTheMath(s) {
    if (!/^[0-9.+\-*\/%() ]+$/.test(s)) {
        throw "Invalid input";
    }
    return eval('(' + s + ')');
}
var result = doTheMath('10*10*10');               // 1000
var result2 = doTheMath('myEvilFunctionCall();'); // Throws exception
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iziye5/2)

That regexp may not be perfect, I'd stare at it long and hard before I'd let any unwashed input head its way...

Comment: +1; it might be easiest to whitelist only numbers and mathematical operators in the input, using a regex.

Comment: @Andy E: Yeah, that could be a way to go if you semi-trust the source. :-)

Comment: +1 Great answer. Use of `eval` where appropriate, warnings of when it isn't, and an alternative (that I was thinking of posting, but cba to come up with.. whew what effort!)

Comment: hey I would mark this as answer if inputs come from arbitrary sources. In case, the values come from a config file in the server. I'm doing js server-side not client so I guess my config file is safe :)

Comment: @runrunforest: I think I would typically trust my config files, but since you're parsing config entries which I assume you do once at startup, I'd probably use the `doTheMath` version just to be <s>paranoid</s> cautious. But a raw `eval` would be totally fine in that case as well, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

this could be achieved quite simply without resorting to eval

```
function calc(s) {

   s = s.replace(/(\d+)([*/])(\d+)/g, function() {
        switch(arguments[2]) {
            case '*': return arguments[1] * arguments[3];
            case '/': return arguments[1] / arguments[3];
        }
   })

   s = s.replace(/(\d+)([+-])(\d+)/g, function() {
        switch(arguments[2]) {
            case '+': return parseInt(arguments[1]) + parseInt(arguments[3]);
            case '-': return arguments[1] - arguments[3];
        }
   })

   return parseInt(s);

}

alert(calc("10+5*4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` function to evaluate an expression in a string:

`var evaluated = eval(s);`

`alert(evaluated)` will then alert `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you "just" want to have these numbers out of the string you can do

```
eval(s)
```

to get "10*10*10" as a Number